# Ubuntu Install Won't Connect to WiFi

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, internet

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.0.4 on a PC that had windows 10 on it a couple days ago (currently it has a broken, half installed Ubuntu). When I try to install Ubuntu, the step for connecting to internet doesn't have any options to actually do so. The only "network" it shows me is `Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.`, which isn't a real network. If I choose "try before installing," it still doesn't connect to the internet, and it freezes if I try to access my settings.

Specs:
The PC is a Lenovo Legion-Y7000P laptop.
CPU: i5 8300H
GPU: usually it just uses the built-in graphics on the CPU, but it also has a GTX 1050 ti

Comment: You have 2 issues that are likely unrelated. The freezing can happen with certain graphics cards and there are workarounds for that so you can install and later add the recommended drivers. The WiFi not being detected is also a matter of drivers, probably, but you can install without internet connection and latter troubleshoot.

Comment: I had a feeling it was something with my drivers, because it was similar to a post on r/linux4noobs that was solved with drivers, but the way they said they fixed it was an incomplete answer that didn't help me fix mine. How do I get those drivers?

Comment: Please [edit] and post your hardware specifications, especially the graphics card, because I have a feeling we need to start with that or it might freeze mid installation again. Dealing with that so you can install the OS properly, then later we should identify your WiFi device and check what it needs.

Comment: Alright I did that

Comment: OK. Now, if possible, in UEFI settings ("BIOS") disable the Nvidia graphics. Running with the Intel shouldn't have freezing issues. Also make sure only UEFI mode is enabled - disable any reference to or support of Legacy/CSM - as this assures the installer will boot (and install) in the correct mode.

Comment: Okay so I've got UEFI boot mode enabled. I don't see anything that would allow me to turn off the Nvidia graphics. For such a gaming-focused PC, it's surprisingly limited in the BIOS. Should I have secure boot on or off?

Comment: Better Secure Boot off. Reason: Later you'll have to install Nvidia drivers and Secure Boot enabled will prevent loading those drivers (and any other unsigned drivers). Dealing with that to keep Secure Boot enabled is somehow complex so better off from the start. It's not really a problem. Now, I suggest booting the installer again as is, and ignore the internet connection (or use an Ethernet cable to the router). If it freezes again then you need to use a workaround: >>>

Comment: >>> In the first menu select "Try Ubuntu" and then press "e" to edit and add `nomodeset` to the same line where "quiet splash" is, anywhere, but making sure there are spaces before and after. Confirm, and it'll boot the live session in low graphics mode (that shouldn't freeze). Proceed with the installation, ignoring the internet connection.

Comment: Okay so I've been waiting on a ethernet over power set which just arrived, so I'm all good on the internet front. I managed to get through every step of the install, but when I boot into Ubuntu for the first time and log in, I just get a purple screen with my cursor on it, and it's frozen.

Comment: It was expected. https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu to boot again with `nomodeset`. Then, with the internet connection, open Software & Updates > Additional Drivers and select and apply the recommended drivers for Nvidia.

Comment: I struggled a bit with getting `nomodeset` because the setup screens were a bit different than in the linked answer. But eventually I got in. Software Updater is doing it's thing right now.